# C Struct values not being assigned

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the [Video4Linux2 API](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/r10386.htm), but something peculiar is happening with the structs that I'm supposed to use to change the various controls on a given camera.  For some reason, some of the members aren't reporting back as changed on assignment.  I wrote the following code to simplify the problem:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int setExtendedControl(int id, int value);
int fd = 0;

int main()
{
    setExtendedControl(20, 30);
    return 0;
}

int setExtendedControl(int id, int value)
{
    struct v4l2_ext_control extControl;
    struct v4l2_ext_controls extControls;

    extControl.id = id;
    extControl.value = value;
    extControl.value64 = value;
    extControl.reserved2[0] = 0;
    extControl.reserved2[1] = 0;
    extControl.reserved2[2] = 0;

    //Put the individual control structure into the
    //multi-control container structure and initialize the container
    //as well
    extControls.ctrl_class = V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_MPEG;
    extControls.count = 1;
    extControls.controls = &extControl;
    printf("extControls.controls = %i, extControl = %i\n", (extControls).controls, &extControl);



    extControls.reserved[0] = 0;
    extControls.reserved[1] = 0;
    extControls.reserved[2] = 0;
    extControls.error_idx = 0;

    printf("Verifying settings:\n");
    printf("extControl.id = %i, id = %i\n", extControl.id, id);
    printf("extControl.value = %i, value = %i\n", extControl.value, value);
    printf("extControl.value64 = %i, value = %i\n", extControl.value64, value);
    printf("extControl.reserved2[0] = %i, set to 0\n", extControl.reserved2[0]);
    printf("extControl.reserved2[1] = %i, set to 0\n", extControl.reserved2[1]);
    printf("extControl.reserved2[2] = %i, set to 0\n\n", extControl.reserved2[2]);

    printf("extControls.ctrl_class = %i, V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_MPEG = %i\n", extControls.ctrl_class,
            V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_MPEG);
    printf("extControls.count = %i, set to 1\n", extControls.count);
    printf("extControls.reserved[0] = %i, set to 0\n", extControls.reserved[0]);
    printf("extControls.reserved[1] = %i, set to 0\n", extControls.reserved[1]);
    printf("extControls.reserved[2] = %i, set to 0\n", extControls.reserved[2]);
    printf("extControls.error_idx = %i, set to 0\n", extControls.error_idx);

    printf ("\nRunning secondary check..\n\n");


    int rval;

    //Set up the individual control structure



    //Try to change the control and return the
    //value reporting the outcome.
    rval = ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS, &extControls);

    if (extControls.controls != &extControl)
    {
        printf("\n\nLost the pointer on initial set!\n");
    }
    //printf("error_idx after initial set %i\n", extControls.error_idx);

    //printf("extControl = %i, extControls = %i\n");

    //freeStructs(extControl, extControls);

    return rval;
}
```

When I run this, the "value" and "value64" members aren't set.  The following is the printf outputs:

```
extControls.controls = -1954893344, extControl = -1954893344
Verifying settings:
extControl.id = 20, id = 20
extControl.value = 0, value = 30
extControl.value64 = 0, value = 30
extControl.reserved2[0] = 0, set to 0
extControl.reserved2[1] = 0, set to 0
extControl.reserved2[2] = 0, set to 0

extControls.ctrl_class = 10027008, V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_MPEG = 10027008
extControls.count = 1, set to 1
extControls.reserved[0] = 0, set to 0
extControls.reserved[1] = 0, set to 0
extControls.reserved[2] = 0, set to 0
extControls.error_idx = 0, set to 0
```

And here is a small snippet from gdb:

```
(gdb) step
printf (__fmt=0x400880 "extControls.controls = %i, extControl = %i\n") at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:105
105       return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
(gdb) step
setExtendedControl (id=20, value=30) at ioctlTest.c:30
30          extControl.reserved2[0] = 0;
(gdb) step
Hardware watchpoint 2: extControl

Old value =
    {id = 4294960502, size = 32767, reserved2 = {4196309}, {value = 0, value64 = 67750802696962048, string = 0xf0b2ff00000000 <Address 0xf0b2ff00000000 out of bounds>}}
New value =
    {id = 20, size = 32767, reserved2 = {0}, {value = 0, value64 = 67750802696962048, string = 0xf0b2ff00000000 <Address 0xf0b2ff00000000 out of bounds>}}
```

It's not happening here, but there have been other instances in a beefier version of this code where the pointer assignment for extControls.controls and int assignment of member extControl.id both fail.  What would cause a struct member assignment failure of this nature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you print out `extControl.value` immediately after assigning it a value?

Comment: The values are set correctly, and then changed by the line
`extControl.reserved2[2] = 0;`.  Don't know why though

Comment: Related to the answer: *why* do you think it's appropriate to store anything at all in a structure member named `reserved...`? If **you** didn't name it so, then it's not reserved for you but for somebody else - don't touch it.

Comment: Nate, the first, and chosen answer explains why it's broken.  I'm blowing off the end of the array into memory that is owned by me, but will react in an unpredictable way.

mlp, I'm not storing anything there.  I'm simply initializing it to zero.  The API documentation link at the top of this post is why I was touching it in the first place.  It states that it must be set to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't check this myself, but looking at this [spec of `struct v4l2_ext_control`](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/r10386.htm#V4L2-EXT-CONTROL) (Table 1), it says:

**Table 1.** `struct v4l2_ext_control`

```
__u32   id      Identifies the control, set by the application.
__u32   reserved2[2]        Reserved for future extensions. Drivers and applications must set the array to zero.

union   (anonymous)      
    __s32   value       New value or current value.
    __s64   value64     New value or current value.
    void *  reserved    Reserved for future pointer-type controls. Currently unused.
```

Note three things here:

- `value` and `value64` are part of a union, they occupy the same location in memory
- reserved2 has size two, so only, `reserved2[0]`, `reserved2[1]`, no `reserved2[2]` !
- according to this spec, `reserved` memory address precedes the union within the struct

This means that when you set

```
extControl.reserved2[2] = 0;
```

you are actually writing outside the memory assigned to that array, overwriting the data of the union, thus altering "both" `value` and `value64` members at the same time.

Comment: Newbie mistake, I knew there had to be something that was causing it.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

See [kernel docs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/media/vidioc-g-ext-ctrls.html) for struct information

The `reserved[]` array for the `v4l2_ext_control` struct is only of length 2...so you're modifying memory that you shouldn't be with the line:

`extControl.reserved2[2] = 0;`

Comment: And the way the struct is organized, `value` comes right after `reserved2`, so overwriting the array will change `value`.